# How do i make comments responsive on my website?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, styling

I am trying to make users comments responsive on my website, so that at full width three show,at tablet size two and mobile one. I have attached the link to the website so you can get more of an idea of what i mean: http://www.bfi-film-festival.com/movie.php?id=269

```
.cmt {
float: left;
width: 100%;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
margin: 15px 0;
}

.cmt_inr {
width: 100% !important;
float: left;
margin: 2%;
min-height: 100px;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
-box-flex: 1;
flex: 1;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 80px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
.cmt_inr {
width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.cmt_inr {
width: 50%;
}
```

The @ media screens i am using don't seem to work and i have no idea why.

Comment: The reason your media queries aren't working is because you are setting `!important` on cmt_inr which will override any other CSS applied to that div class.

Answer (score 0):

the "{}" are missing for the @media-tag

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) "{"
"}"
```

Try this to see a result:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .cmt_inr {
        background-color: red;
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .cmt_inr {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 20%;
    }
}
```

The "!important" would override the witdth so try to avoid it or set the !important for the widths in the @media-tag too.

Comment: Sorry they weren't missing, i just forgot to add them in when i wrote in the script. I also took out the !important when testing in the inspect element but this hasn't made any difference.